# Is there a viable cross-browser library for Sencha-like cube transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I found the 3d cube transition of Sencha Touch very attractive and want to use it for a web site. However, Sencha only works in WebKit browsers (although not so well in Chrome).

So, is there an alternative library which works in modern browsers, with touch support?

Comment: I'm a tad confused; are you asking for an alternative to Sencha Touch; or something like Sencha Touch but is cross-browser compatible, whilst retaining touch and CSS animations?

Comment: I mean just the cube transition effect, similar to the one provided by Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best implementation is this one: http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html

While not nearly as smooth as the solutions which use the WebKit 3d transform functionality, it does its job.